# Traning New Entities in Spacy NER Model

Tags: python, spacy

I want to add new entities to python spacy NER module. I have few doubts regarding this.

1. Is it possible to remove some of the presently existing entities and add new entities to the remaining ones.
2. While training new entities, I found we have to provide training data in a particular format. For example,

   data = [
   ("I love chicken", [(8, 13, "FOOD")]),
   ...
   ]

Instead of sentences like "I love chicken", is it possible to give data like

```
data = [
    ("chicken", [(1, 8, "FOOD")]),
    ... 
]
```

Will this affect accuracy.

Comment: I would look spaCy's pattern matching rules. They will allow you to develop something similar to what you are looking for. You can always then train a model off of those rules, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how NER works:

- NER is not about recognizing only a fixed set of entities, it's about detecting *any entity* in a text. For example it should detect an entity in "Mr X said ..." whether X is "John Smith" or "Donald Duck".
- This implies that NER uses clues from the sentence in order to detect entities, as opposed to just tagging entities that it knows from training.

Therefore

> 1. Is it possible to remove some of the presently existing entities and add new entities to the remaining ones.

No, because the NER model is not a list of entities, it's a complex model using text features.

> 2. Is it possible to give data like [...]

Technically you can give data like this but it's not the way it's supposed to work.

You seem to be interested in matching exactly a set of predefined entities, NER is not the right tool for this. In this scenario it's much simpler to store your entities in a list and apply string matching to the text.